# Masked functions in R

Tags: r

This is a newbie question in R. If you have two libraries in R with same function name (and one masking the other) then how do you use the masked function.
A concrete example:
Both UsingR and QRMlib have the function QQPlot(), and UsingR's QQplot is masking that of QRMlib. How can I use the QQplot function of QRMlib.
Thank you

Addition: Just found out that QRMlib::QQplot() works, thus modifying the question that I found in the web. What if they don't have a namespace in which case the above approach will not work.
Link to the original question posed in google:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-March/067710.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UsingR::QQPlot()` and/or `QRMlib::QQPlot()`

Try to load preferred library last, since it will mask the "unwanted" function...

All the best!

Comment: Thanks.. just found that out in the web. Please see the addendum

Comment: Try `An Introduction to R - W. N. Venables, D. M. Smith and the R Development Core Team, (ISBN 3-900051-12-7)`, chapter `13.3 Namespaces`

Comment: All CRAN hosted packages now require a NAMESPACE.