# How do I use functions in one R package masked by another package?

Tags: r

I would like to use `recode` from the `car` package.  But if I have `Hmisc` loaded, it masks the `car` version.

There is probably a way to call the masked function.  Perhaps there is also a way to force one package to be the dominant one?

Comment: you can use something like this `car::recode` and `Hmisc::recode`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2842120 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4879377

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could run into deeper problems, but at the top level `car::recode` should do the trick. Not sure what happens if recode uses functions that are also masked.

Comment: +1 for *"Not sure what happens if recode uses functions that are also masked"* - good point!

Comment: That is something package maintainers need to be aware of. Shouldn't be a problem if everything is properly imported and namespaces are used.

Comment: i believe namespaces are always used now (R>=2.14)

Answer (score 6):

Use the namespace (package name): `car::recode`.