# How to specify from which library a function is used?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: Masked Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879377/r-masked-functions)

I am using the packages `moments` and `fUnitRoots`. Both of them have a function called "kurtosis" (to be more precise, the package `fUnitRoots` calls the package `timeDate` which also has the function "kurtosis"). They give very different results, because their formulas is slightly different. I want to use the function skewness from the library `moments`, but if the two libraries are loaded, the function used is the one from `fUnitRoots`.

How can I specify from which library I want the given function to be used, *without unloading one of the libraries*?

Comment: duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337716/how-do-i-use-functions-in-one-r-package-masked-by-another-package, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842120/masked-functions-in-r, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879377/r-masked-functions

Comment: You might consider searching before posting.

Comment: @DWin I did search, on google and here, and I even browsed through the suggestions once my question had been written. I am very aware of how unforgiving people here are with duplicate questions, but I had a problem, I needed help, and if I have to be afraid of this type of comment or the closing of my questions, I will no longer use this site.

Comment: @Vivi: I don't know what you used for search terms, but searching for the message, "The following object(s) are masked from" provides several hits on Google, Stack Overflow, rseek.org, etc.  I don't think it's unreasonable or unforgiving that people expect you to search for the message, error, or warning before posting.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich it might be obvious for you that "masked" is a key word in my question, but it is not obvious to me (and I still don't see the connection). I used the terms "[r] choose library function clash" (and repeated the search without the word clash) and I got nothing on google and hundreds of answers here. If I didn't ask, I wouldn't have found the answer. If the question is a duplicate, close it; I don't take it personally. But I really don't see why the assumption is that I didn't search and why people feel the need to tell me off.

Comment: @Vivi: The only reason it was obvious to me to search for "The following object(s) are masked from" is because that's the message you get when you run `library(moments); library(fUnitRoots)`.  I ran the code, it gave me a message, I searched for the message.  It's that simple.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I didn't read the messages, and it is fair to say I should have, but I don't think it is fair to assume I was lazy or to be told to search before asking, with the presumption I haven't. This doesn't help. Anyway, thanks for pointing out the message, I will make sure I read the stuff that comes up when packages are loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `::` operator. The syntax is `package::name`. So it would be `moments::kurtosis`.

Comment: Perfect! I need to wait 8 minutes to accept, but that solves my problem :)

Comment: How can one ask R to always use the function from a particular library in the current workspace? This solution will entail typing the library name and :: each time the function is called.